# Exterior Robin Boundry Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, self-learning

Exterior Robin boundary is expressed as the following in the book 
$\partial{u}/ \partial{v}-\lambda u=f$ on the boundary and $v$ is normal. Also u satisfies Laplace Equation in exterior domain in $R^2$

$u=O(1/r)$ when $|x|=r\to\infty$

Here i do not understand why  $1/r$  is written.
Can we write $1/r^2$ or  $1/r^3$ instead of $1/r$  ?
 We know $1/r^2$ is faster when $r \to \infty$. But i did not see this in the book. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details, it depends on a variety of things.

Comment: Of course $O(1/r^n)$ implies $O(1/r)$ for $n\ge 1$, the statement given is likely the weakest necessary for the results to hold.

Comment: Is there any relation between power of $r$ and dimension of $R$?